# Vue - Accessing Attributes From One Component to Another

Tags: vue.js

New to vue and struggling to understand how data is passed back and forth between components.  I'm aware of props and emit on the parent/child, child/parent, but I can't quite understand how they work in my case.  I have two components: a parent component called "Letters" and a child called "ClaimantSearch".  Claimant search return data about a person based on a call to a flask backend:

```
<div>
  <b-form @submit="onSubmit" class="w-100">
      <b-form-group id="form-title-group"
                    label="Claim Number:"
                    label-for="form-claim-number-input">
          <b-form-input id="form-claim-number-input"
                        type="text"
                        v-model="claimNumberForm.claimNumber"
                        required
                        placeholder="Enter claim number">
          </b-form-input>

          <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
              @click="getClaimant(claimNumber)">
            Get Claimant
          </button>
        </b-form-group>
    </b-form>
    <span v-if="claimant">
      <p> {{ claimant.name }} </p>
      <p> {{ claimant.address1 }} </p>
      <p> {{ claimant.address2 }} </p>
      <p> {{ claimant.city }}, {{ claimant.state }} </p>
      <p> {{ claimant.zip }} </p>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      claimant: '',
      claimNumberForm: {
        claimNumber: '',
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getClaimant(number) {
      const path = `http://localhost:5000/claimant/${number}`;
      axios.get(path)
        .then((res) => {
          this.claimant = res.data.claimant;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
    onSubmit(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      this.getClaimant(this.claimNumberForm.claimNumber);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I then have a Letters parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <claimant></claimant>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import axios from 'axios';
import ClaimantSearch from './ClaimantSearch.vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      claimant: '',
      claimNumberForm: {
        claimNumber: '',
      },
    };
  },
  components: {
    claimant: ClaimantSearch,
  },
  methods: {
  },
};
</script>
```

What I'd like to be able to do is access `{{claimant}}` outside of the `<claimant>` tag, if that makes sense.  So inside Letters I'd like to do something like:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div>
      <claimant></claimant>
    </div>
    <div>
      Dear Mr. {{claimant.name}},

      Please get bent.  Sincerly, crappy insurance company.
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: lmao, I really hope you work in insurance and are rebelling with this

Comment: Also, what you're looking for is global state - `vuex` is the best for it

Comment: great, i read about that but i wasn't sure if it was overkill for this use case.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember exactly where I found this link, but there's an *excellent* post on medium, with code samples, that discusses all the state management patterns in vue starting with props and events, eventbus, simple store and then vuex.

https://medium.com/fullstackio/managing-state-in-vue-js-23a0352b1c87